# Obtaining Windows service handle in Python

Tags: python, winapi

I need to work with services on Windows (10) from Python (version 3). Before starting and stopping them, i need to obtaing service handle. First, I obtain SCManager handle (successful), and after that I trying to obtain service handle via `OpenService` (in example it is "Dhcp" service). This is my code:

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *

OpenSCManager = windll.advapi32.OpenSCManagerA
OpenService = windll.advapi32.OpenServiceA
GetLastError = windll.kernel32.GetLastError

SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS = DWORD(0xF003F)
SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS = DWORD(0xF01FF)

name = "Dhcp"

sc_manager_h = OpenSCManager(None, None, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS)
if sc_manager_h == 0: 
    raise Exception(GetLastError())
else:
    print(sc_manager_h)  # <-- OK, no exception, printed some number

service_h = OpenService(sc_manager_h, name.encode("ascii"), SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS)
if service_h == 0:
    raise Exception(GetLastError()) # <-- here raised Exception, GetLastError is 6 (ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE)
else:
    print(service_h)
    print(GetLastError())
```

User (i ran under Administrator), that runs code, have all right (i tried to run under user without rights, and `OpenSCManager` raised correct error). I'm also sure that it is not a problem with name or service asscess constant, there is another `GetLastError` codes for that. Service with such name ("Dhcp" in my case) exist. **Seems** like somehow I pass SCManager handle to `OpenService` in wrong way, but i don't know how else.

Documentation on `OpenService`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684330(v=vs.85).aspx

**Update 1**

As @conio suggested, i tried equivalent C code, and it works well. Also i tried run code above on next machines\interpreters:

- Windows XP, Python 3.4.3: Works well, `service_h` is not 0,
  GetLastError is 0;
- Windows 7, Python 3.4.3: Works well, `service_h` is not 0, GetLastError is 0;
- Windows 7 (same machine as previous), Python 3.6.2: Works wrong, `service_h` is not 0, GetLastError is 6, and `service_h` can be used to other service functions, like `StartService`
- Windows 10, Python 3.4.3: Works well, `service_h` is not 0, GetLastError is 0;
- Windows 10 (same machine as previous), Python 3.6.2: Works wrong, `service_h` is 0, GetLastError is 6, exception raised.

Summarize this tests:

- Python 3.4.3 works well;
- Python 3.6.2 works wrong, it always set GetLastError to 6, but sometimes it return 0 from `OpenService` and error raises in code above, and sometimes it return correct handle, which can be used in other service functions like `StartServiceA`, and this functions works well (at least i tried to start service and it starts).

Comment: Have you tried the equivalent C code? (And why are you using ANSI functions?

Comment: @conio updated post.

Comment: Note that calling `GetLastError()` that way is very likely to be meaningless. Between the call to `OpenService` or whatever and the point the interpreter gets to the call to GLE a lot of stuff can happen, and that stuff might change the last error. You didn't mention it, but I'm going to use my psychic powers and say the problems happens only with 64-bit Python. I'd recommend using pywin32 instead of all this mess.

Comment: @conio, hm, your psychic powers is strong, really, 3.4.3 is 32-bit and 3.6.2 is 64-bit. But i can't get it, how it could affect working with WinAPI? And as i remember, pywin32 doesn't compatible with latest python versions.

Comment: I see PyWin32 builds for Python 3.6 and 3.7. In what sense is it not compatible? The problem with 64-bit is pointer sizes. Something gets messed up there with Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

OpenSCManager = ctypes.windll.advapi32.OpenSCManagerW
OpenSCManager.restype = wintypes.SC_HANDLE
OpenSCManager.argtypes = [
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,
    wintypes.DWORD,
]
SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS = 0xF003F
sc_manager_handle = OpenSCManager(None, None, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS)

OpenService = ctypes.windll.advapi32.OpenServiceW
OpenService.restype = wintypes.SC_HANDLE
OpenService.argtypes = [
    wintypes.SC_HANDLE,
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,
    wintypes.DWORD
]
SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS = 0xF01FF
service_h = OpenService(sc_manager_handle, u"XblGameSave", 0xF01FF)
```